# Como recuperar base de sql server eliminada desde object explorer?

Tags: sql-server

Existe algun modo de recuperar una base de datos eliminada desde el object explorer de sql server

Comment: Desde el último backup no es opción?

Comment: el ultimo backup de esa base de datos se guardo hace dos meses

Comment: Sabes la ubicación de los datafiles? Están los archivos en esa ubicación?

Comment: no encuentro los .mdf y .ldf

Comment: Entonces tu pregunta no es sobre bases de datos, sino si esos archivos eliminados se pueden recuperar. Una vez los tengas, recuperar la base de datos es trivial. Mi primera sugerencia sería que cese toda actividad en el equipo en cuestión, para evitar que los sectores que contenían los archivos sean utilizados para algo más. No soy experto en sistema de archivos, aunque he escuchado que hay utilitarios que te permiten recuperar un archivo borrado.

Comment: En cualquier caso, mientras el equipo siga en uso, dado que ahora está marcado como "espacio disponible", podría utilizarse para cualquier cosa. 
Siendo Windows, no se si cabe la posibilidad qua el eliminar la DB el Management studio haya enviado los archivos a la papelera de reciclaje  y no los haya eliminado directamente. Vale la pena revisar.

Comment: Quizá sea una medida muy extrema pero si intentas restaurar tu equipo a un estado anterior , antes de la eliminación  :) , tus archivos `ldf` y `mdf` se guardan en `C:\Users\NameUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Instances\Projects`

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que no tienes un entorno de replicación/failover, tus opciones básicas son estas:

## Reutilizar los archivos de datos

Al eliminar la base de datos utilizando MSSQL Management Studio, los datafiles son eliminados también del sistema. Si puedes recuperarlos intactos, crea la base de datos *atachando* los mismos archivos originales, ejecutando un script similar a este:

```
USE [master]
GO

CREATE DATABASE [MiBase] ON
( FILENAME = N'D:\Mi\Ruta\De\Datos\MiBase.mdf' ),
( FILENAME = N'D:\Mi\Ruta\De\Datos\MiBase.ldf' )
 FOR ATTACH
GO
```

Esta es la mejor solución pues no tendrás perdida de datos.

## Recuperar desde un backup

Las copias de seguridad son imprescindibles en cualquier sistema de producción. Si tienes un esquema de backups completos+incrementales, puedes reducir la pérdida de información a minutos, y si no, con backups completos, dependiendo del tamaño de los datos, lo habitual es tener un backup en las últimas 12 a 24 horas. No es lo ideal, pero es mejor que nada.